# How to write percent character into a file using variable argument list, va_list, va_start, va_end

Tags: c++, c, printf, variadic-functions

I need to use `%%` in format string in order to write `%` character like this:

```
printf("%%");
```

I am trying to do this in my variable argument list function. Format specifiers work fine such as `%d`, `%s` etc. But when I try to write `%` character using `%%`, it doesn't work. Why and is there any solution?

```
void foo(LPCSTR sFrmtStr, ...)   
{   
    char buffer[4096] = { 0 };

    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, sFrmtStr);
    vsprintf(buffer, sFrmtStr, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    printf(buffer);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Worth trying format `%c` with an argument value `'%'`?

Comment: After a few seconds of thought, "it doesn't work" isn't too hard to figure out...

Comment: What I mean is, it doesn't write anything. %c is not working either. Also, if someone calls this function using %% format in order to mimic printf, it won't be a good solution to use %c.

Comment: Why the [tag:c++] tag? I can't see any c++ specific code in the example. That would work in c++ as well, but ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of *course* "it doesn't work".  You're calling `printf` with a string that has a single `%` in it after calling `vsprintf()`:

```
void foo(LPCSTR sFrmtStr, ...)   
{   
    char buffer[4096] = { 0 };

    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, sFrmtStr);
    vsprintf(buffer, sFrmtStr, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    /* Now buffer holds a string with a single '%' in it */
    printf(buffer);
}
```

The fix:

```
void foo(LPCSTR sFrmtStr, ...)   
{   
    /* doesn't need to be initialized */
    char buffer[4096];

    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, sFrmtStr);
    /* assume vsnprintf is available */
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof( buffer ), sFrmtStr, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    /* puts() is probably better... */
    /* and fputs( buffer, stdout ) is even better... */
    fputs( buffer, stdout );
    /* printf("%s", buffer); */
}
```

Comment: And `puts string)` is probably better than `printf("%s", string)` if you're writing a single string to `stdout`.

Comment: `fputs(s, stdout)`. `puts(s)` is equivalent to `printf("%s\n", s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with the following usage:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char* sFrmtStr, ...)   
{   
    char buffer[4096] = { 0 };

    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, sFrmtStr);
    vsprintf(buffer, sFrmtStr, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    printf(buffer);
}

int main()
{
  foo("n=%d pct %%\n", 23);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

n=23 pct %

However, gcc rightfully does not like it with a warning about printf(). Better use puts() instead of printf(), then you do not have to worry about stray % characters that printf might try to interpret.

Comment: Try it with `foo("n=%d pct %%s\n", 23);`